# Should I run cable through pipe?

Tags: wiring, drywall, pipe, plastic, spackling-paste

[image: how it was before]

I drilled a hole in my wall and ended up creating this mess. I plan on fixing it with spackle. The cable is a communications wire, not an electrical wire. Would it be appropriate to stick a plastic pipe inside the wall to run the wire(s) through in order to make it easier?

Finished product after response
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Better plan: cut out the damaged drywall and install a low-voltage bracket and coax barrel wallplate

Some cheap-arse folks do what you see here -- simply punch a hole in the drywall to run low-voltage cabling through.  While this sort-of-works, it leads to ugly results like the ones you see here.  It's much better to do the neat and tidy thing and install a low-voltage old work bracket and coax barrel wallplate instead.

[image: old work low voltage bracket] [image: coax wallplate]

Installation is as follows:

1. Cut out the damaged drywall to match the cutting template for the old work bracket you're using
2. Install the old-work bracket using the clamps that come with it -- you'll have to run the coax through it first to do this in your case
3. Undo the existing barrel connection between the two lengths of coax
4. Screw the coax from the wall onto the back of the barrel wallplate
5. Attach the wallplate to the bracket
6. Attach the removed coax cable to the front of the wallplate

Comment: Thanks again for the help. Just finished installation, works and looks great. Added photo to OP.